# Scan directory for files with specific extensions recursively

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find all files in folder and subfolders with specific extensions.

```
 $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
 $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
 $files = new RegexIterator($iter, '/.*\.(src|in|out|rc)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

My output should look like this `var_dump()`

```
  array(105) {
  [2]=>
  string(6) "00.out"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "00.src"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "01.out"...
}
```

Actual result

```
object(RegexIterator)#4 (1) {
  ["replacement"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Where am I doing mistake?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What does the current code do and what do you want it to do? Maybe you want `ALL_MATCHES` instead of `GET_MATCH`?

Comment: @chris85 That didn't work neither

Comment: Okay, so can you describe what the current behavior is? Do you get an error, too many matches, not matches, etc.

Comment: You do not convert the iterator to an array in your example, so that part for sure is missing. You also have not shown what you get instead so it is not entirely clear into which problem you run. Could be the matching group of the regular expression, but there can be a plethora of issues you run over, so it is perhaps helpful if you describe the issue a bit more by showing the unexpected result.

Comment: @chris85 I added result

Comment: Since `$files` is an Iterator instance, you need to iterate it, e.g. `$files->next(); print_r($files->current()); ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the PHP [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function does what you want:

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern
>   according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is
>   similar to the rules used by common shells.

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

And here is a nifty function by [agd243](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#111217) that uses glob() to find all files by extension an return it as an array:

```
function findFiles($directory, $extensions = array()) {
    function glob_recursive($directory, &$directories = array()) {
        foreach(glob($directory, GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT) as $folder) {
            $directories[] = $folder;
            glob_recursive("{$folder}/*", $directories);
        }
    }
    glob_recursive($directory, $directories);
    $files = array ();
    foreach($directories as $directory) {
        foreach($extensions as $extension) {
            foreach(glob("{$directory}/*.{$extension}") as $file) {
                $files[$extension][] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
var_dump(findFiles("C:\\baseFolder", array (

    "src",
    "in",
    "out",
    "rc"
)));
```